# How to stop a button to take the value after certain condition meet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a simple tic tac toe game app using java.it is working as required, but after wining form one side it is keep taking the value. How to stop the execution after certain condition meet.
If this is one of the condition of declaring the winner

```
  else if (b1.equals(b4) && b4.equals(b7) && !b4.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Winner is " + b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

then what should do to stop taking the input from all the button until restart?

Comment: paste some code here to better understand the problem.

Comment: You can disable all the button cells, or you can show some kind of persistent dialog informing that the game has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You can always disable the buttons after that condition is met:

```
button.setEnabled(false)
```

Since you're saying you don't want the user to continue the game after it ended, you can also create an alert dialog, telling the game has ended, and when the user clicks "Ok" it restarts the game:

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
  
        // Set the message show for the Alert time
        builder.setMessage("Winner is (insert winner name)");
  
        // Set Alert Title
        builder.setTitle("Game Ended");
  
        // Set Cancelable false for when the user clicks on the outside the Dialog Box then it will remain showing
        builder.setCancelable(false);
  
        // Set the positive button with Ok
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) (dialog, which) -> {
            // When the user click yes button then restart the game
            restartGame(); //Create this function to restart the game, for example
        });
  
        // Create the Alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        // Show the Alert Dialog box
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have tried first method and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i get your question but you can do it in while loop such as

```
while(condition){
 // take the value
 }
```

and you can just update the value of condition after it finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can set button.setEnabled(false) after your condition is satisfied.